# Import error for csv file azure databricks

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-databricks

I have a csv file which has a lot of text data. I am trying to import it in azure databricks using python pandas but it is giving me a long list of errors but primarily its telling me this:- ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module. However, when I am putting file in local desktop and then importing it on local desktop using jupyter/spyder it is imported without any errors.
I have also put in option of encoding UTF-8 while importing it in azure databricks but its still showing error. Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. had to enter encoding=cp1252. Not sure about it why i had to put this option but tried several and this worked. There were several symbols and brackets in the text data fields so this might be useful when importing similar data and facing such problems